# What is another word for "ugly side"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is another word for "ugly side"?
How do I say "X reveals the ugly side of Y" in another way?

Edit: Sorry, I should've made this clearer.
I wanted another word for "ugly side" but without the "side" if you get what I mean.

For example: "This reveals the ugly side of his ideal"

I was thinking of using 'ugliness' instead of 'ugly side' but I wanted to know if there were better options.

Comment: *unseemly side*?

Comment: Hello and welcome to WL&U. Stack Exchange answers are supposed to be authoritative. As the question currently stands, that doesn’t seem possible. Please [edit] your question to explain the nuance you’re trying to express.

Comment: I find the question clear. The use of the placeholders X and Y may seem to require more examples of nuances but for the PO to give them would answer the question for which they seek our help.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I edited my post so hopefully this made my question clearer.

Comment: "Ugly side" is a vague phrase: it can refer to moral failings or bad consequences or inconveniences or gaps. We have "bad side", "hidden face", "loophole", "blind spot" in the answers, all of which mean different things.

Answer (score 2):

I can offer a few options, all emphasised in bold:

> Trust me. You don't want to get on his **bad side**.
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20someone%27s%20good%2Fbad%20side)

> The **hidden face** of Primark fashion
>
> [Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2008/jun/22/india.humanrights)

**The Mr Hyde** and **The dark side**

Mr Hyde is a part of the novel *The Strange Case of Dr Jekyll and Mr Hyde*, by R L Stephenson.

> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_Case_of_Dr_Jekyll_and_Mr_Hyde) Jekyll is a kind and respected English doctor who has repressed evil urges inside of him.[1] In an attempt to hide this, he develops a type of serum that he believes will effectively mask his **dark side**. Instead, Jekyll transforms into Edward **Hyde**, the physical and mental manifestation of his evil personality.[2] This process happens more regularly until Jekyll becomes unable to control when the transformations occur.

> **Alter ego**: the part of someone's personality that is not usually seen by other people
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/alter-ego)

> Many fiction writers, like Stephen King in his 1989 novel, The Dark Half, see the **other self** as a figure of repressed violence and evil.
>
> [Medium.com](https://medium.com/s/real-magic/discovering-your-other-self-f6decd9dfff)

Comment: Supplied the link. "_Dark side"_'s best!

Answer (score 0):

A *loophole* of his ideal.
A *blind spot* of his ideal.
A *flaw* of his ideal.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the ELU. On this site users are encouraged to provide references for the information they give.